# unsolicited image in excel cannot be removed

Tags: microsoft-excel, images

Using Excel 2016 for a cash flow.  An image of a purchase I made at target.com.au randomly appeared in the spreadsheet. The image stays in the same section of the spreadsheet (around row 4365) even if I insert rows.  The image cannot be grabbed, moved, clicked on or anything similar.  If I mass deleted the whole contents of the worksheet the image stays.

Bizarrely the image only appears on the monitor/laptop where you open the excel file and when I drag the spreadsheet to the attached screen the image disappears. That is; I open excel on the laptop and the image is visible, I then drag it to monitor and image disappears.  Reverse also applies if opening excel on the monitor first.

I tried opening this file on my husband's excel 2019 and same issues.
I used the Alt F11 hack recommended on an earlier thread but no results found.

I have found a temporary work around in saving the cash flow under a different name, deleting the work sheet, copy/paste the 4500 lines of data to a new blank work sheet and the image so far has not appeared. So I have a temporary file name on it, but hoping to understand what is going on here.  How can an image appear without intervention by the user and not be able to be impacted by user.
Note I ran Norton 360 and malwarebytes on the file as a security check, but no results.
Although I have a temporary work around I would like to understand what is going on.

PS I am not an IT professional but a little bit techie and if the explanation is simple I can work it out.  Please help me so I know I am not going mad!!

Comment: A possible solution I found online was to activate a new worksheet, type something in it, and then switch back. The user reported that after he did that the image was deletable again. You may wanna give that a try. You may have multiple worksheets selected/grouped. Try rightclicking on the sheet tab, and then click Ungroup.

Comment: thank you Gantendo,  I tried both but neither worked.  Interestingly now sometimes the image disappears but once you save the spreadsheet and re open it re appears again.  There is no way to click on it or grab it.  It also does not appear in a print preview.  The work sheets were not group but I did a group and ungroup to be sure and no change occurred.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, very strange behavior. glad you found a work around. My thoughts center around some kind of VBA injected into your original file. This would only be true if the file has the appropriate extension to run macros. Having said that, VBA put in the personal.xlsm (or personal.xlsb) can run code on a .xlsx file. So maybe check for that.

Comment: (Do this on a copy of the file) rename the file with a .ZIP extension, then open that. Navigate to \xl\media\ can you find the image there? If yes, remove it, rezip the file and rename it back with a .XLSX extension, then try to open it. Note: you may get an error message, but with a bit of luck the rest of the file will be OK

Comment: You are not going mad. We feel your pain.

Comment: thank you everyone for your helpful suggestions.  Unfortunately I am non the wiser but have learned a lot from your feedback.  I think I just need to move on and feel assured I am not going mad! LOL.  Thank you again.